# Is there a way to inherit the template of an abstract parent model class in Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I've got an abstract `Page` model that defines common fields for a type of page that I then subclass to restrict the types of subpages allowed. I'd like all of the subclasses of this abstract model to default to using the `template` defined in the abstract model, but it seems like they don't.

```py
class BaseListing(Page):
    empty_message = RichTextField()
    intro = RichTextField()

    template = 'listing.html'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BlogListing(BaseListing):
    subpage_types = ['BlogPost']
```

I'd like wagtail to default to using the template defined in the `BaseListing` model, but it looks for a `blog_listing.html` template unless I specifically set `template` on the `BlogListing` model like this:

```py
class BlogListing(BaseListing):
    subpage_types = ['BlogPost']
    template = 'listing.html'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define [a `get_template` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#dynamically-choosing-the-template) on your abstract page model. Normally, the default implementation of `get_template` will simply return `self.template` (which in turn defaults to a filename derived from the class name, giving the behaviour you're currently seeing).

The most common use of `get_template` is to vary the template on a per-request basis (to serve a different template for authenticated users, for example); however, if you define it to return a fixed template name instead, this will override the standard behaviour of each subclass getting its own template.